# How to map UTF-8 symbols to numbers in command-line mode?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

Sometimes I change input source (keyboard language) and my number buttons get mapped to rarely used UTF-8 symbols, e.g. `1` gets changed to `ą`, `2` to `č`, `3` to `ę`,  etc.

I have managed to map them in normal mode to numbers by using these mappings:

```
map     ą           1
map     č           2
map     ę           3
map     ė           4
map     į           5
map     š           6
map     ų           7
map     ū           8
map     „           9
map     “           0
```

However these mappings don't work in command-line mode (after pressing `:`) - original symbols are used. Is there a way to tell VIM that when I enter `ą` in command-line mode I mean 1?

Comment: Doesn't help for command-line mode, but you might like to take a look at [`:help 'langmap'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27langmap%27), to handle this in normal mode without having 10 separate mappings. Try `:set langmap=ą1,č2,ę3,ė4,į5,š6,ų7,ū8,„9,“0`

Comment: @Rich Wow, that's even better oO Thank you!

Comment: @Rich I came here to talk about langmap... You should turn that into an answer. (Even if it doesn't address command-line mode directly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:map` command only creates mappings for normal, visual, select, and operator-pending modes. To add commandline mappings you need to use `:cmap` in addition to the `:map`.

`:help map-modes` has a table describing which map command maps in which mode:

```
     COMMANDS                    MODES
:map   :noremap  :unmap     Normal, Visual, Select, Operator-pending
:nmap  :nnoremap :nunmap    Normal
:vmap  :vnoremap :vunmap    Visual and Select
:smap  :snoremap :sunmap    Select
:xmap  :xnoremap :xunmap    Visual
:omap  :onoremap :ounmap    Operator-pending
:map!  :noremap! :unmap!    Insert and Command-line
:imap  :inoremap :iunmap    Insert
:lmap  :lnoremap :lunmap    Insert, Command-line, Lang-Arg
:cmap  :cnoremap :cunmap    Command-line
:tmap  :tnoremap :tunmap    Terminal-Job
```

You can use a for loop if you don't want to define all map commands more than once:

```
let s:maps = {
    \ 'ą': '1',
    \ 'č': '2',
\ }
for lhs, rhs in items(s:maps)
    exe printf(':map %s %s', lhs, rhs)
    exe printf(':cmap %s %s', lhs, rhs)
endfor
```